# Populating listview with parse.com when user offline

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I have a problem in my application. My listview is filled with data coming from parse.com, but when the user is not connected to the internet, the listview is empty. I would not have a way to save the adapter of listview while the user is online to display the listview offline?

I tried in various ways and read the parse.com documentation, but to no avail. Here is my code.

```
public class Eventos extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ListViewEventos adapter;
    private List<GetEventos> eventos_lista = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eventos);

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Eventos.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando Dados...");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            eventos_lista = new ArrayList<GetEventos>();
            try {
                // Localizando a classe noticias no parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "Eventos");
                //colocando por ordem de data
                query.orderByAscending("Number");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject titulo : ob) {
                    // Localizando as imagens na coluna foto do parse
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) titulo.get("Foto");
                    ParseFile img = (ParseFile) titulo.get("FotoEvento");

                    GetEventos eventos = new GetEventos();
                    eventos.setTitulo((String) titulo.get("Titulo"));
                    eventos.setDescricao((String) titulo.get("Descricao"));
                    eventos.setTextoEvento((String) titulo.get("TextoEvento"));
                    eventos.setFoto(image.getUrl());
                    eventos.setFotoEvento(img.getUrl());
                    eventos_lista.add(eventos);
                }

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewEventos);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewEventos(Eventos.this,
                    eventos_lista);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse natively supports both query caching and a local datastore (which uses SQLite under the hood), it can be as easy as:

```
final String TOP_SCORES_LABEL = "topScores";

// Query for the latest objects from Parse.
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(final List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
    if (e != null) {
      // There was an error or the network wasn't available.
      return;
    }

    // Release any objects previously pinned for this query.
    ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground(TOP_SCORES_LABEL, scoreList, new DeleteCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
          // There was some error.
          return;
        }

        // Add the latest results for this query to the cache.
        ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(TOP_SCORES_LABEL, scoreList);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Some more information can be found in the Parse [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-caching-queries), this all ofcourse relies on your app being online at least once.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use SQLite to store data temporarily.

SQLite library for Android that I often use
1. [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/)
2. [GreeDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/)

The first step to retrieve data from the server, and then stored in the local database. The next check, whether the device is connected to the internet or not.

Comment: I'm using parse.com as database . From what I read in the documentation, there is a way to record parse the data on the device , but do not know how

Comment: parse.com a cloud media storage, so if there is no internet connection, then the data is in the application can not be used, use local storage.

Comment: synchronization of data from the server to the local

Comment: And it's how to parse the data coming from the local store ?

Comment: Please read docs [parse.com] (https://parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore)